# C# parameter depends on enum value

Tags: c#, function, methods, types, parameters

I am looking for a solution for that kind of functionality. Is that possible? Maybe with generics?
I would to have an Add-Function where the parameter type is depending of the enum value.
I know there are some other solutions but I would to see/have that solution.

```
public enum eSomeEnum
{
   //only Int32
   Value1 = 1,
   //only string
   Value2 = 2,
   //only MyClass
   Value3 = 3,
}

private void Test()
{

   Int32 n1 = 61;
   string s2 = "Hello";
   MyClass c3 = new MyClass();


   //correct
   Add(eSomeEnum.Value1, n1);
   Add(eSomeEnum.Value2, s2);
   Add(eSomeEnum.Value3, c3);

   //wrong type
   Add(eSomeEnum.Value3, s2); --> Compiler Error
}
```

Comment: Sounds extremely like an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info). Please explain what you are doing with the two parameters in `Add`, and maybe we can help you rewrite `Add`.

Comment: @Sweeper
I have a simple solution for that (AddMyClass, AddSomeObject, etc) but I try to learn more options C# and I thought, maybe that is possible.
I wanted just ask.
My Class create some SQLite-Statements and I need for every kind of enum value another type of parameter (Dictionary, SomeClass, List, string, int, etc).
Is a big topic.

Answer (score 0):

This is not something that can be enforced directly at the signature level; for `Add(eSomeEnum.Value2, s2);` to be legal, the signature `Add(eSomeEnum, string)` must be valid, which means `Add(eSomeEnum.Value3, s2);` must be valid.

You *might* be able to write a Rosyln analyzer that spots this pattern and flags it as a warning, but that is a fairly advanced topic. It also won't be able to cover all scenarios, for example where the enum used is not a literal, but is an expression result. You may just have to depend on runtime validation/exceptions here.

Alternatively, consider having methods like:

```cs
public void Add(int value) => Add(eSomeEnum.Value1, value);
public void Add(string value) => Add(eSomeEnum.Value2, value);
public void Add(MyClass value) => Add(eSomeEnum.Value3, value);
// (and your existing Add method, now 'private')
```

Now the caller *can't get it wrong*. This can be extended if multiple enums are valid per type:

```cs
public void AddFoo(string value) => Add(eSomeEnum.Value2, value);
public void AddBar(string value) => Add(eSomeEnum.Value3, value);
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution, it looks like overloaded functions. I never saw those kind of overloading. Thanks for that idea!